# How to call method from activity to change layout?

Tags: java, android

How can I call the `changeTitle()` method of `VideoLayout` inside the `onItemClick` event of the activity?

I'm trying to figure out what's the best practice to change the content of a list item.

Doing `v.changeTitle((VideoModel) videoAdapter.getItem(position).title);` (which I think it's the the first solution that's come up to my mind) throws a "undefined method" error.

Any toughts?

I won't explain the code because I think it's self explanatory:

---

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    public void setVideosList()
    {
        videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(this, videoItems);
        listView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long arg3) {

        }
    });
    new getVideosTask().execute();
}
```

}

video.xml (I just pasted the beggining of it. This layout is what goes inside a list item)

```
<com.company.project.VideoLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="15dp"
android:paddingTop="15dp"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:id="@+id/wrapper">
```

VideoAdapter.java:

```
public class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    VideoLayout view;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = (VideoLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.video, parent, false);
    }else{
        view = (VideoLayout) convertView;
    }

    VideoModel item = (VideoModel) getItem(position);
    if (item != null) {
        view.prepare(item);
    }

    return view;
}
}
```

VideoModel.java:

```
class VideoModel {

public String title;
public String videoUrl;
public String imageUrl;
```

}

VideoLayout.java:

```
class VideoLayout extends LinearLayout{
public Context context;

public MyImageView imageView;
public MyVideoView videoView;
public TextView titleView;

public VideoLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public VideoLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public VideoLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

protected void onFinishInflate()
{
    super.onFinishInflate();
    imageView = (MyImageView) findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
    videoView = (MyVideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
}

public void changeTitle(String text){
    titleView.setText(text);
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    View wrapper = view.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
    if(wrapper != null && wrapper instanceof VideoLayout) {
        wrapper.changeTitle("title");
    }
}
```

Comment: I got a related question: when I try to show a Toast inside the `changeTitle ` method, it throws a `nullPointerException` error on this line. It seems like the context on which the toast shows up is NULL. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you paste the Toast Code?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I've simplified it (based on @thinear's answer):

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            VideoLayout wrapper = (VideoLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
            wrapper.changeTitle("title");
        }
```

Comment: It now started to behave in strange ways: when I click on the second row, it seems that `changeTitle` applies to other items as well.