# Listview item click applying to other items

Tags: java, android

I have this on my main activity:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                TextView wrapper = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
                VideoModel o = (VideoModel) videoAdapter.getItem(position);
                wrapper.setText(o.title);
            }
        });
```

This code (as you would guess) changes the textview of a list view row (which is a layout).
The problem is that for some reason when I click on the first row, the text changes, but it also changes on the third row (with the same text).

Any toughts?

If you want to see the whole code, refer to [How to call method from activity to change layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296066/how-to-call-method-from-activity-to-change-layout)

Comment: You want to only show the title of the item that is clicked??

Comment: in this case yes, but this is just an example

Answer (score 0):

Don't change Views in setOnItemClickListener instead change your data and notify adapter so that adapter will change your UI.

Example:

Model

```
class VideoModel {

public String title;
public String videoUrl;
public String imageUrl;
public boolean isTitleVisible;
}
```

Adapter

```
    public class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        VideoLayout view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = (VideoLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.video, parent, false);
        }else{
            view = (VideoLayout) convertView;
        }

        VideoModel item = (VideoModel) getItem(position);
        if (item != null) {

            view.prepare(item);
if(item.isTitleVisible){
view.changeTitle("");
}
        }

        return view;
    }
    }
```

On click listener:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position,
                long id) {
           videoItems.get(position).isTitleVisible=! videoItems.get(position).isTitleVisible;
videoAdapter.notifyDatasetChange();
        }
```

This is just an example in which you change your view model and just notify adapter to change the view in onITemClick

Comment: can you give me some example?

Comment: Checkout the edited ans, I have added an example of how to do this.

Comment: Ok, I got it! Thx. But what if I want to change let's say the color of the text, or the size of an image? Where do I include all the methods that change UI (that don't necessarily involve changes in the data)?